# Let f(x) be a cubic polynomial....(Complete question in image below)

Tags: derivatives, polynomials

[image: Question:]

Here i dont really understand what they mean by 'f(x) has negative local minima'.
I considered it as the value of x at which minima occurs should be -ve.
Considering that, we get;
f"(x)=2x+2a-6>0, therefore x>3-a
from f'(x)=0 we get x= (3-a) ± sqrt[(a-4)(a-2)]
Since x>3-a, we will only consider 3-a + sqrt[(a-4)(a-2)]
For this we get x -ve for all values from 4 to 50. Therefore i am getting the answer as 2444.
But the given answer is 1265. Can someone please point out where i am wrong or provide a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You've found a range of values where $f$ has a stationary point for $x < 0$, but you haven't ensured that $f$ is negative at those stationary points.

Comment: I have found the values of 'a' for which x<0, and f is minimum....

Comment: The question might be to find the cases where f is negative, but then how would we actually do it?

Comment: You have a formula for $f(x)$. Plug your value of $x$ into $f(x)$, and test whether that is positive.